# jQuery Mouseover / Mouseout will not work with Live

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code that when I do an ajax call, it refreshes a column but then the mouseover no longer works. I used to have it inline in the div but wanted to move it to jQuery for other reasons. this is my code.

```
$(".statusbox").live({mouseover:function(){
    wal_id = parseInt(this.id.replace("statuscontainer_", ""));
    $('#rm_'+wal_id).show();
},mouseout:function(){
    wal_id = parseInt(this.id.replace("statuscontainer_", ""));
    $('#rm_'+wal_id).hide();}
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(".statusbox").live( 'mouseover', function() {
    wal_id = parseInt(this.id.replace("statuscontainer_", ""));
    $('#rm_'+wal_id).show();
}).live('mouseout', function() {
    wal_id = parseInt(this.id.replace("statuscontainer_", ""));
    $('#rm_'+wal_id).hide();}
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but same result. It works until I hit refresh and it repopulates the column, then it doesn't :(. I don't get it. All the other functions sill work with the live, just not the mouseover portion.

Comment: have you tried just puting an alert or console.log function inside your mouseover function?  Is it possible that $('#rm_'+wal_id) is not finding the element you're intending?

Comment: Thank you for helping me to debug this. The code indeed was working but for some reason the contents of the div was not there after the ajax so it probably has worked all along. Thanks for the following up to help me solve my "user error" moment.

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct syntax for live:

```
$(".statusbox").live( 'mouseover', function() {} );
```

Comment: I got my syntax directly from jquery.com in the demo http://api.jquery.com/live/ for mouseover

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".statusbox").live("hover", function(){
   ...
}, function(){
   ...
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work at all. does hover support multiple event handler functions now?